Trying to promote a build that was created by appending two other builds. The build is released, but the artifacts are not copied to the other repo
I'm trying to publish a build in Artifactory using the CLI.  The build, My_Build_Name, was created by appending two previous builds My_Build_Name_1 and My_Build_Name_2.
jf rt build-append My_Build_Name 20 My_Build_Name_1 20
jf rt build-append My_Build_Name 20 My_Build_Name_2 20

jf rt build-publish My_Build_Name 20 --build-url=$JOB_SUMMARY_LINK

jf rt build-promote --source-repo=release-staging-repo --status=Released --include-dependencies=false --copy=true --fail-fast=true --dry-run=false My_Build_Name 20 release-repo

Artifactory logs seem to show it promoted successfully, but the artifacts never get copied over to release-repo from release-staging-repo.

2024-05-20T23:58:31.527Z [1;32m[jfrt ][0;39m [34m[INFO ][0;39m [xxxxx] [o.a.e.UploadServiceImpl:477   ] [p-nio-8081-exec-1274] - Deploy to 'artifactory-build-info:My_Build_Name/20-1716249405979.json' Content-Length: 1078 (estimation) artificial: false
2024-05-20T23:58:31.604Z [1;32m[jfrt ][0;39m [34m[INFO ][0;39m [xxxxx] [o.a.b.BuildPromotionHelper:187] [p-nio-8081-exec-1274] - Promotion completed successfully for build name 'My_Build_Name' and number '20' under repo 'artifactory-build-info' with status of 'Released'

Any ideas on why this might be happening?  Let me know if there's other information that's needed?
I appended both builds My_Build_Name_1 and My_Build_Name_2 to My_Build_Name, then ran a build-promote on My_Build_Name, but the artifacts never got copied.  I was expecting all artifacts under the appended build to get copied.
The build My_Build_Name does show Released, as it looks like artifactory-build-info was updated.
--dry-run was false.

Finally found this issue on the jfrog-cli.  https://github.com/jfrog/jfrog-cli/issues/1275.  Looks like the only solution is to promote each of the sub builds. :(
